# Honeywell T6360 wiring from Hive

Tags: wiring, thermostat

[image]I’m wanting to swap my thermostat over from a Hive one to Honeywell. I’ve attached a photo of the current Hive wiring and the new thermostat.

Please can someone guide me on how to move the wiring over? Thank you[image]

[image]

Comment: The ground is pretty obvious, as are 1-4. What does the manual say about the location of the line & neutral wires? If you're not sure, it would help to [edit] in a picture of the wiring diagram from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no HVAC expert, but based on the wiring diagram and the existing wiring, this is what I'd do.

Existing stat:

- Black from wall goes to `N`
- Red from wall goes to `L`
- Black jumper connects `L` to `1`
- Grey from wall goes to `3`
- Bare/Green ground goes to `ground`

New stat:

- Black from wall goes to `2` (that's your Neutral)
- Red from wall goes to `1` (that's your Line)
- Grey from wall goes to `3` (that's to the furnace)
- Bare/Green ground goes to `ground`

**Disclaimer:** Guaranteed to have less than a 100% chance of success.

Comment: Hahaha thanks. I tried that, but it didn’t work.

Comment: Before or after my answer. If before, woulda been nice to know that...

Comment: I tried it after you suggested it

Comment: @LeahBrown -- pay attention to the labels on the new thermostat -- the terminals go ground-2-3-4-1 instead of ground-1-2-3-4